# Expression not saving in QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

When I try to enter the following expression to remove NULLS, it does not appear to be saving/doing anything.

if( "number" IS NULL, 0, "number")

1. Open Attribute Table
2. Open Field Calculator
3. Check **Update Existing Field**
4. Double-click **Field and Values**
5. Paste this expression on my applicable value
6. Press OK

My field still appears NULL for all rows.

Edit: I am working with a joined field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is correct, the only issue I can think of is that you didn't select the target field from the drop-down menu. The one you need to update:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

I used QGIS 3.4.5.

Comment: My desired field does not appear in the [drop down](https://imgur.com/a/Ld67k3X). If it helps, this Attribute Table is my shape file, and the field I'm trying to remove the NULLs from is from my data set.

Comment: @Jon The field name is invalid that is why you cannot see it in the drop-down list. The field name cannot exceed 10 characters in shapefile: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00126-00150-000142.htm. Also slash character `/` is invalid. You need to create another field with correct name (no special characters) and length.

Comment: Thank you. I've shortened the name, but it still automatically adds the underscore before it. It's now "AA_Arabic." "AA" referring to my data spreadsheet. "Arabic" the data column in my table. How can I change the name to remove the underscore?

Comment: @Jon The underscore was added because spaces are not acceptable also, but underscore is a valid character. Can you see the field in the drop-down list?

Comment: I still cannot see it. I only see the original fields in my shape file, not the joined field from my data source.

Comment: ah, looks like in your original question you failed to mention that you're trying to do this on a joined field! maybe do the join, then export the file to a new shapefile so that the joined field is embedded in the shape.

Comment: @Jon You should mention in your question that you are working with joined field. SaultDon comment should fix the issue by exporting the shapefile into a new file to make the join permanent.

Comment: This worked. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

Editing a field in-place (i.e., writing output to it when it itself is the input) appears to not be working because you're doing this on a joined field. A work-around, as long as you it's not a problem to lose the join, would be to use your expression as it is, but write to a new column; then delete the previous column that contains NULL values; and then rename your new column to the same name as the old one.